# Stack Fails on Sanity Check with Sandboxed GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc, gmp, haskell-stack

I am getting a very strange error relating to freshly installed, sandboxed GHC that was created from `stack setup`. 
It looks like it's related to `/usr/bin/ld`

Thanks for your help in advance! I'm new to Linux in general as well.

```
tristan@tristan-System-Product-Name ~ $ stack setup
The GHC located at /home/tristan/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see 

    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/installiandiupgrade/ 

for more information. Exception was: 
Running /home/tristan/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc /tmp/stack-sanity-check10861/Main.hs -no-user-package-db in directory /tmp/stack-sanity-check10861/ exited with ExitFailure 1 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main        (/tmp/stackrsanityrchecklosﬁl/Main.hs, /tmp /stackrsanityrcheck10861/Main.0 ) 
Linking /tmp/stackrsanityrcheck10861/Main 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Comment: What's your Linux distro? Try installing libgmp3-dev.

Comment: Instead of a picture, use actual text.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint latest.